# Reference shortcut

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I am new to OSX/linux. I have all my development stuff in the following location:

```
~/Dropbox/Dev/CompanyA
```

Is there anyway I can create a link to that folder by just referencing `~/dev` or something? I have no idea if that is possible. But every time I have to reference this long path for lots of things I do in terminal.

I get the concept of aliases in terminal (`editing ~/.bash_profile`). But I am looking for something more on the system level (*outside of just terminal if possible*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a *symbolic link* to that directory, somewhere convenient. I would not use the word *dev* which in *Nix systems is a directory of its own, let' s call it *mydev*.

```
     ln -s ~/Dropbox/Dev/CompanyA ~/mydev
```

This creates a symbolic link, called mydev, in your Home directory (change its location or name  as you prefer). Now, every time you need something in ~/Dropbox/Dev/CompanyA, you may just use *mydev* instead. For instance,

```
     cd ~/mydev
```

lands you inside ~/Dropbox/Dev/CompanyA transparently (*i.e.*, without you noticing anything). You can read files there,

```
     more ~/mydev/myfile.txt
```

or create subdirectories

```
     mkdir ~/mydev/newsub
```

and they will magically appear in ~/Dropbox/Dev/CompanyA. Basically, you can do through *mydev* **everything** you want to do in ~/Dropbox/Dev/CompanyA.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to know is the difference between a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) and an [Alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)).

Symbolic Links are from Unix and are available to use in OSX and Linux. Aliases are icon representations of other items (files or folders) and are equivalent to a Windows Shortcut.

For developing software, a Symbolic link is best.
For easy access to a folder in the Mac OS Finder, you would create an Alias.